# Find Exactly four integers from array that sum up to given N and the integers needs to maximize their end product

Tags: algorithm

Please note, I am not asking for code here, but I'm seeking an approach and explanation if possible.

Given an array of integers and Integer N how can we approach to find exactly four integers that will on summing up will become equal to N. There is a condition that we should find four such integers A,B,C,D which would maximize the product

> AXBXCXD

Example **N is 60** and array is

> 30,20,15,12,10,6,5,4,3,2

There are many possibilities of finding four integers, some of them are as shown below

**Possibility 1**

> 30+10+10+10=60 --> final AXBXCXD=30*10*10*10=30000

**Possibility 2**

> 15+15+15+15=60 -->final AXBXCXD=15*15*15*15=50625

The correct answer is 50625 among all possible A,B,C,D integer sets and their products and it has to be our final output.

**Another example N is 8**

> Array is of 2 integers  4,2

Possibilities of making sum with four integers A,B,C,D is only one and it is as follows.

> **2+2+2+2=8 final output 2X2X2X2= 16**

If array has no such possible combination of four integers to sum up to N we have to print -1 actually. That's where the array has no such possible integers.

By looking [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum) I understood how recursively we can approach to solve the problem to find out subsets of array which sum up to N. But I don't understand how can we enforce the exact four integers condition from above problem statement.

Comment: This is called a "subset-sum" problem and is quite famous in computer science. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of examples, tutorials, lectures, and textbook problems on this exact problem.

Comment: also, needs to maximize the product.

Comment: "I am not asking for code here, but im expecting an approach and wonderful explanation if possible." would sound better as "I am not asking for code here,, I am asking for an approach and an explanation, if possible".

Comment: @JohnDonn Yes edited

Comment: Can't genetic algorithm solve this by selecting 4 random values as parameters and maximizing multiplication if sum is 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Compute the sums of every pair and its product
- Sort it by sum
- For every pair that sum X, find the one that sums N - X with the highest product
- Store the product of the 2 pairs as max between that and previous max
- Once done, display max product

Complexity: O(n^2 * 2 log n).